# Casting Live HLS to Android TV

Tags: android, google-cast

I am implementing Google Cast for my video app (min API 16) with live HLS streams. I follow the instructions https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#5 and stopped in step 6. When I tap on cast button, Cast dialog appears, I select my Android TV device (test device Mibox 3, Android 6), remote player is trying to load video, but instead of HLS live video I see a big red title SAMPLE on TV. I decided to play sample video http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8 and again I see SAMPLE. If I tap on cast button again, dialog indicates: no media file was chosen. Locally I use ExoPlayer to play HLS live video without problems. I tried MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED and MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE

Code:

```
private void setupCastListener() {
        mSessionManagerListener = new SessionManagerListener<CastSession>() {

            @Override
            public void onSessionEnded(CastSession session, int error) {
                onApplicationDisconnected();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionResumed(CastSession session, boolean wasSuspended) {
                onApplicationConnected(session);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionResumeFailed(CastSession session, int error) {
                onApplicationDisconnected();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionStarted(CastSession session, String sessionId) {
                onApplicationConnected(session);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionStartFailed(CastSession session, int error) {
                onApplicationDisconnected();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionStarting(CastSession session) {}

            @Override
            public void onSessionEnding(CastSession session) {}

            @Override
            public void onSessionResuming(CastSession session, String sessionId) {}

            @Override
            public void onSessionSuspended(CastSession session, int reason) {}

            private void onApplicationConnected(CastSession castSession) {
                mCastSession = castSession;

                if (clickedChannel != null) {
                    if (isPlaying()) {
                        loadRemoteMedia(true);
                    }
                }

            }

            private void onApplicationDisconnected() {

            }
        };
    }

    private void loadRemoteMedia(boolean autoPlay) {
                if (mCastSession == null) {
                    return;
                }
                RemoteMediaClient remoteMediaClient = mCastSession.getRemoteMediaClient();
                if (remoteMediaClient == null) {
                    return;
                }
                remoteMediaClient.load(buildMediaInfo(), autoPlay);
            }

    private MediaInfo buildMediaInfo() {
                MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);

                mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, clickedChannel.getName());

                selectedStreamingURL = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8";

                return new MediaInfo.Builder(selectedStreamingURL)
                        .setContentType("application/x-mpegURL")
                        .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                        .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
                        .build();
            }
```

Comment: It's probably not the solution but try setting MediaInfo content type to `"video/mp4"`. Also do you see any warnings / errors in logs?

Comment: in the tutorial they use "videos/mp4", did not help. Did not find errors from remote player.

Comment: I tried to play http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8 in example project from tutorial, the same problem - SAMPLE instead of video. Android TV can't play HLS?

Comment: tried to play example https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/mp4/DesigningForGoogleCast.mp4 in my app, it works, but again with SAMPLE label on top of video. Who adds this label?

Comment: tried without success: return new MediaInfo.Builder("http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8")
                .setContentType("application/vnd.apple.mpegurl")
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE)
                .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
                .build();

Comment: found a new problem, after upgrading device to Android 8, cast button is disabled, and enabled on devices with previous versions of Android.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by changing this method

```
@Override
    public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {
        return new CastOptions.Builder()
                .setReceiverApplicationId(CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: I got many exceptions, problem is described here https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/issues/35